# How do I add a custom domain to my GAE app? Domain from GoDaddy

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I bought a domain from GoDaddy.com and I've been trying to connect that as a custom domain to my app engine project.

My project is a static website made in python using the flask framework. I currently have the stock url provided but I want to connect a custom domain purchased from GoDaddy. I updated the records under manage DNS settings on GoDaddy with the ones provided when I mapped my domain in the App Engine settings. I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) on Google Cloud documentation.

What am I doing wrong? The site shows up as can't be found when I try to access it through the custom domain.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs more detail before other people can help you. For example, please provide details on what you mean by "the ones provided when I map the domain to my project". Have you been provided with `A records` that you need to add? When you say "The site comes up as can't be found" do you mean that this happens after visiting the site in a web browser? Which specific instructions from GoDaddy have you already followed?

Comment: Does `your-app-name.appspot.com` come up?  Did you verify the domain, then update the CNAME, A, AAAA records as outlined in that tutorial?

Comment: Yes, my xxxx.appspot.com works. Yes, I updated the CNAME, A, AAAA as outlined in the tutorial. I put my domain name as the host but I could be wrong here.